# Workflow Formula Help

Tags: community, workflow, formula

I'm trying to setup a workflow rule condition.  The field is Record Type and it is a picklist field.

```
ISPICKVAL(RecordType.DeveloperName, "Prospective Customer")
```

Anybody know why I'm getting this error

> (Incorrect parameter type for function 'ISPickVal()'. Expected
>   Picklist, recieved text.

Can someone help me with this formula?

Answer (score 2):

The `RecordType` field is not a picklist, it's a system lookup field. You can just do:

```
RecordType.DeveloperName == "Prospective Customer"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your developer name is the name with no spaces, rather with underscores, I would assume you have Prospective_Customer as the DevName, so you would use:
$RecordType.DeveloperName = "Prospective_Customer"